# How to ignore some templates in helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm reading helm documentation,

> The templates/ directory is for template files. When Tiller evaluates a chart, it will send all of the files in the templates/ directory through the template rendering engine. Tiller then collects the results of those templates and sends them on to Kubernetes.

I have lots of different templates in my template folder, I'm looking for a way to skip those templates that start with "y" and "z" and don't send it to Kubernetes, is there any way I can achieve that? I want to be flexible let's say if statementProvider is x, skip all manifests starting with y and z and do not send it to Kubernetes.

I wrote this helper function to extract the list of resources that should be deployed in Kubernetes but I don't know how I can use it:

```
{{- define "statement.resource"}}
{{- $statementProvider := lower ( $.Values.statementProvider ) -}}
{{- $statementFiles := list -}}
{{- range $path, $bytes := .Files.Glob "templates/**" }}
    {{- if eq $statementProvider "x" -}}
        {{- if not (or (hasPrefix $path "y") (hasPrefix $path "z")) -}}
        {{- $statementFiles = append $statementFiles $path -}}
        {{- end }}
        {{- $statementFiles -}}
    {{- end }}

{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with simple `if` statement.

Your `template` file

```
{{- if .Values.serviceAccount.enabled -}}
...
{{- end }}
```

Your `values` file

```
serviceAccount:
  enabled: true/false
```

You also can do the same for resources that are nested and conditional add `volumet` to your `deployment`.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, yes but I have a lot of files in my template, is there any way to apply this rule to a group of resources? let's say all resources start with something. or even apply t his rule to a sub-directory in the templates directory?

Comment: Let say you have app with 5 resources that should be enable all or nothing. Then you can place those in `charts --> my-app` directory. After that in every template please include suggested `if` statement (`{{- if .Values.my-app.enabled -}}...`) and in `values.yaml` file put `my-app --> enabled: true/false`. With such configuration you would be able to disable whole app in specific directory.

Answer (score 1):

What I'm gonna suggest is along the lines of what Michał has already done, but with a small tweak that might work for you.

So, your `template` can look something like this:

```
{{- if .Values.apply_template.true }}
...
{{- end }}
```

and add this to your `values.yaml`:

```
apply_template:
  true: true
  false: false
```

Now, as you mentioned: "to skip those templates that start with "y" and "z"", you can run this simple `cmd` that would replace `true` with `false` in the templates that start with `y` and `z`.

```
find . -type f \( -name "y*.yaml" -o -name "z*.yaml" \) -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' "s/true/false/g" | helm template .
```

You will still have to change your templates (one time) to add the `if` statement, but beyond that, you can control which templates you wanna skip going forward. I have only very quickly tested this on a couple of temp templates (and it works fine), but I hope this gives you some headway to achieve what you wanna do.

You might have to tweak the `cmd` a bit given that I'm running it on OSX - in case you are not (I guess you might have to git rid of the single quotes `''`.